# NSTask blocks main thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nsthread, nstask

From my main thread I call a selector using

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startTask) withObject:nil];
```

This is the method startTask:

```
-(void)startTask{    
   NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
   NSFileHandle *fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

   NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-z",iPAddress, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",portNumber], nil];

   [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/nc"];
   [task setArguments:args];
   [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

   NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   [nc removeObserver:self];
   [nc addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(dataReady:)
              name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification
            object:fh];

   [task launch];
   [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];
}
```

This should prevent NSTask from blocking the main thread (and the UI). But it doesn't.
If I remove

```
[task launch];
```

The main thread doesn't get blocked. What am I doing wrong? o_O

(BTW dataReady just handles the data. It's not this method, that blocks...)

**EDIT:** I just found out, that I am not calling the selector from the main thread. I call it from a separate thread! Unfortunately I have to call it from that thread.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676508/nstask-blocking-the-main-thread, you're approach seemed to work in that case.

Comment: Please take a sample of your application while its main thread is blocked and edit your question to include the stack trace of the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer to your question, but you do have a fundamental issue:

The docs for [readInBackgroundAndNotify](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-readInBackgroundAndNotify) say:

> You must call this method from a thread that has an active run loop.

You are not doing that because `startTask` is on its own thread and you are not running a run loop on it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I remove readInBackgroundAndNotify or not. The problem remains. But you are right. I should also chance that. I edited my question!!! I found out, that I am not calling the selector from the main thread. I call it from a separate thread!

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, that's what JeremyP said.

Comment: I misunderstood the answer. That is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the issue is but I suggest looking into NSOperationQueue.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
   NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
   NSFileHandle *fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

   NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-z",iPAddress, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",portNumber], nil];

   [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/nc"];
   [task setArguments:args];
   [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

   NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   [nc removeObserver:self];
   [nc addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(dataReady:)
              name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification
            object:fh];

   [task launch];
}];
[queue autorelease];
```

Lemme know if you have any questions

In the documentation heres some info on [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) just if you were wondering:

> Operation queues usually provide the threads used to run their
>   operations. In Mac OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues use the
>   libdispatch library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate
>   the execution of their operations. As a result, operations are always
>   executed on a separate thread, regardless of whether they are
>   designated as concurrent or non-concurrent operations.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Though I recommend to change this one line from "[nc removeObserver:self]" to "[nc removeObserver:self name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification" object:fh]". Otherwise you're running danger to remove this whole instance from all notifications.

Comment: @auco ah fair enough, I usually create a class to deal with all these things for me so the only notifications I get are these notifications. Faulty assumption on my part though